# Null termination of C string

Tags: c, c-strings, null-terminated

Is it right to say that the **null** terminating C string  is automatically added by the compiler in general?

So in the following example:

```
char * str = "0124";
printf("%x", str[str[3] - str[2] + str[4]]);
```

the output is always 32?

Thanks.

Comment: The output will probably not be 32 on an EBCDIC machine.

Comment: -1 Why are you interested in that weirdo `printf` output? This just distracts from your question, doesn't it? Please reformulate.

Comment: It gives me a warning "deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' ". You should use char const* str = "0124"

Comment: @DanielFischer But (I believe) `printf("%c", str[str[3] - str[2] + str[4]]);` should print "2" even with EBCDIC.

Comment: @Dukeling Indeed (modulo the glyphs used, but that's beyond the scope of the language). That is mandated by the standard.

Comment: @Dukeling: it would because the EBCDIC terminal yould recognize 0xf2 as '2'. If you redirected the output and examine the binary contents you would find 0xf2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the compiler does add the null terminator. Thus there is 5 bytes of memory allocated to str off the stack.

By the looks of it, with that string literal, (str[3] - str[2] + str[4]) evaluates to (52 - 50 + 0), so you are acessing str[2], which will print 0x32 in hex.

Answer (score 3):

First question: yes

Second question: yes on a ASCII system: you calculate `'4' - '2' + '\0'` which is in integers: `0x34 - 0x32 + 0` = 2 so you get `str[2]` which is `'2'` which is 0x32. 
`'4' - '2'` to be 2 is defined in C, but if you ran your code on an EBCDIC system, `'2'` was 0xf2

Comment: FWIW: `'4' - '2' + '\0'` would be 2 regardless if ASCII, EBCDIC, or any other conforming C character set as digit characters are required to be consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

The terminating null character is added by the compiler; 6.4.5p6:

> 6 - In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte
>   character sequence that results from a string literal or literals.  The multibyte character
>   sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just
>   sufﬁcient to contain the sequence. [...]

The `printf` output will be the character code of the `2` character on your system.  The characters `0` to `9` are guaranteed to have contiguous codes (5.2.1p3), but not to have any particular value.